# Cannot put ListView inside Column in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, layout, singlechildscrollview

I need listview inside the Column(which is the child of SingleChildScrollView), but it is not showing up!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class BalanceScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24), child: Center(child: Text('15 960 UZS',),),),
            Container(height: 48, alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24), 
              child: Row(children: [Text('Refill balance',), Spacer(), FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.chevronRight, size: 15,),],),),
            
            ///this is causing problem! But i need listview here
            ListView(
              children: [
                Text('some text 1'),
                Text('some text 2'),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is showing up in terminal:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SingleChildScrollView` should be removed and `ListView` should be wrapped with `Expanded` widget

```
 Expanded(   
      child:ListView(
              children: [
                Text('some text 1'),
                Text('some text 2'),
              ],
            )
       )
```

Since the ListView height is infinite and Column widget wants to height value of children. It gives an hasSize expection

Comment: Expanded does not help, But Container is not going to work for me, I will need ListView inside ListView

Comment: @Akbar Pulatov ListView inside a ListView is not a good practice I think. If you can explain what is your main purpose I will suggest some another solutions.

Comment: this is really  good solutions for overlapping wegihts

Answer (score 4):

Adding **shrinkWrap: true** inside ListView should resolve the error

Comment: It does the job temporarily, but the list become unscrollable. I removed the SingleChildScrollView and wrapped ListView with Expanded widget.